# how to change json format from array to object?

Tags: php, json, jsoup

I need some description how to correct print format of json
my code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    //Step 4 Action current row
    $img = $row['image']; 
    $link = $row['link']; 

    $posts[] = array('img'=> $img, 'url'=> $link);

    //echo $row['image'] . "<br/> " ;
    //echo $row['link'] . "<br/> " ;

}
echo json_encode($posts, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The output

```
[

    {
        "img": "catalog\/demo\/banners\/iPhone6.jpg",
        "url": "index.php?route=product\/product&amp;path=57&amp;product_id=49"
    },
    {
        "img": "catalog\/demo\/banners\/MacBookAir.jpg",
        "url": ""
    }
]
```

I want:

```
    {
        "img": "catalog\/demo\/banners\/iPhone6.jpg",
        "url": "index.php?route=product\/product&amp;path=57&amp;product_id=49"
    },
    {
        "img": "catalog\/demo\/banners\/MacBookAir.jpg",
        "url": ""
    }
```

Comment: Use `json_encode();` without JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

Comment: What you want is not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a valid format of JSON

```
{
    "img": "catalog\/demo\/banners\/iPhone6.jpg",
    "url": "index.php?route=product\/product&amp;path=57&amp;product_id=49"
},
{
    "img": "catalog\/demo\/banners\/MacBookAir.jpg",
    "url": ""
}
```

you have a `,` separator, that separates what? 
you have to make it as array.

Comment: you mean that a valid  format of json should be without separator

Comment: @Amassi No. If you want to have *multiple objects*, they need to be contained within an array. The output you're getting is already perfectly fine.

Comment: No, JSON is basically a presentation of javascript object, you can't make object that equals to that. your format is `[object,object,object]` which is `[{},{},{}]`. you can make it as key value object which is ugly `{0:{},1:{}}`